# How to get extra attributes in "resource" element of an OBR repository?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bnd, obr, bndtools

We try to get [Apache Felix Web Console](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) OBR plugin working with OBR repos produced by the current [BND Tools](http://bndtools.org/)/[Bindex](https://github.com/osgi/bindex).

The problem is that the generated repositories (for example, produced with "Release Bundles" from Eclipse) cannot be read by the Felix Web plugin.

To the contrary, the [Felix' own OBR repository](http://felix.apache.org/obr/releases.xml) is properly understood by the plug-in,  since it seems to have additional attributes within the "resource" element, which are missing in our repository:

```
...
<resource 
   id="org.apache.felix.bundlerepository/1.4.1"
   symbolicname="org.apache.felix.bundlerepository"
   presentationname="Apache Felix Bundle Repository"
   uri="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.bundlerepository/1.4.1/org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-1.4.1.jar"
  version="1.4.1">
...
```

The schema specification in http://www.osgi.org/download/rfc-0112_BundleRepository.pdf leaves the room for the attributes within the "resource" XML element, however they are defined as a part of Java API.

This gitHub fork seems to do the job https://github.com/rkrzewski/bindex but does anybody know what is the status of this? Will this be integrated to Bindex some day? **UPDATE**: here is the answer from Rafał, this forks' owner https://github.com/rkrzewski/bindex/issues/3#issuecomment-27784279 
So, I have reasked on bndtools-users Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bndtools-users/ZdY0ASnLNmc

Or are there any other ways to get the OBR repos be generated with the missing resource attributes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The development of Bindex moved to https://github.com/bndtools/bindex.
(source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bndtools-users/R3U2SDazTjY/OyOVTK8DZHUJ) 
Does this version create the proper format for you?

Comment: No, the current Bindex version does not support these attributes.